# What does it mean that each conductor is characterized by a constant value of potential?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

My book mentions this:

> In a system of conductors of arbitrary size, shape and
>   charge configuration, each conductor is characterised by a constant
>   value of potential, but this constant may differ from one conductor to
>   the other.

Here is a screenshot to give better context to the above lines:

[image]

Comment: What specifically about it confuses you? My explanation would have basically just been the first paragraph in the picture you posted.

Comment: @Chris - Since there is no electric field on the surface or inside the surface, why is the potential difference inside and on the surface not zero? Why is it said it will be a constant value? The book also said that any charge given to a conductor resides on its surface. Why?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but *type it out instead* so it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 0):

In an electrostatic field the surface of an ideal conductor has constant potential $\phi$ means  that the electric field intensity vector $\mathbf{E} = -\mathbf{grad}\phi$ is perpendicular to the surface at all points of the conductor.

Answer (score 0):

The potential *difference* inside one conductor is zero. The *potential* is not.

In particular, two conductors can have a potential difference between them, so the two conductors have different potentials.

Comment: Okay, so why the potential not zero as well. I mean there is no electric field inside the conductor. So how can an electric potential exist if there is no electric field?

Comment: There can be electric fields, and thus potential differences, between conductors. In this case, if one conductor is at zero potential then all the others can't be as well. All this means is that it takes energy to move a charge from one conductor to another.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to understand. Inside and on the surface of any conductor, there has to be a constant electrostatic potential because any gradient in this potential is an electric field that would lead to currents which cannot be sustained in an electrostatic situation. Thus in any conductor charges redistribute in such a way that there is always a zero electric field inside the conductor. In typical conductors like metals, with high concentration of charge carriers surface charges build up to produce the constant potential, and thus zero electric field, inside and along the surface.